# flush rewrite rules doesn't flush them (still got 404)

Tags: plugins, rewrite-rules

So I tried to make a simple plugin for WordPress. Like a reviews. Even tried to do it through the tutorial of TutsPlus.
Everytime I got 404 when tried. Then I just took the code from tutor and still got 404 on viewing my review post type post.

```
    function my_custom_posttypes() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'               => 'Testimonials',
        'singular_name'      => 'Testimonial',
        'menu_name'          => 'Testimonials',
        'name_admin_bar'     => 'Testimonial',
        'add_new'            => 'Add New',
        'add_new_item'       => 'Add New Testimonial',
        'new_item'           => 'New Testimonial',
        'edit_item'          => 'Edit Testimonial',
        'view_item'          => 'View Testimonial',
        'all_items'          => 'All Testimonials',
        'search_items'       => 'Search Testimonials',
        'parent_item_colon'  => 'Parent Testimonials:',
        'not_found'          => 'No testimonials found.',
        'not_found_in_trash' => 'No testimonials found in Trash.',
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels'             => $labels,
        'public'             => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui'            => true,
        'show_in_menu'       => true,
        'menu_icon'          => 'dashicons-id-alt',
        'query_var'          => true,
        'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'testimonials' ),
        'capability_type'    => 'post',
        'has_archive'        => true,
        'hierarchical'       => false,
        'menu_position'      => 5,
        'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail' )
    );
    register_post_type( 'testimonial', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'my_custom_posttypes' );

// Flush rewrite rules to add "review" as a permalink slug
function my_rewrite_flush() {
    my_custom_posttypes();
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'my_rewrite_flush' );
```

on top was php opening tag and plugin info (as usual).
Tried it with several themes - still got 404.
Before every test I saved changes on Permalinks and deactivated && activated that plugin.

Anyone got any ideas? I'm just learning for now (yesterday started).

Comment: 404 where?  Trying to access what?

Comment: Trying to view the review! Please, try to read the text first!

Comment: http://screencloud.net/v/gQog  is it clear now?

Comment: After the edit, yes.  It helps to be clear when asking a question you want an answer to.

Answer (score 0):

It might be an .htaccess issue. Sometimes I try to flush the rewrite rules from the command line and it doesn't rewrite the .htaccess file until I go into the /wp-admin section, go to 'Settings > Permalinks' and just save it without making any modifications. See if that works.

Comment: It's ok now.
Tried on Windows 7, all went fine after WordPress update on MAMP.
Tested then on Ubuntu 15.04 after WordPress update, it works flawlessly. Don't really know, why, but the actual thing is that - it works!
Thanks for support!